# Why do I get a stackoverflow error when trying to checkout code using GitSCM class in Jenkins through shared library?

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

When I'm putting the GitSCM syntax generated using the Pipeline Syntax generator in a scripted Jenkinsfile it seems to work fine.

Jenkinsfile:

```
node('Maven Agent') {
   stage('Checkout') {
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'Github-Creds', url: 'https://github.com/some-user/some-repo.git']]]);
   }
}
```

However, as soon as I take out the stage and put it in a groovy shared library function and invoke the function from the Jenkinsfile, it gives me a stackoverflow error after running recursively multiple times.

Modified Jenkinsfile:

```
node('Maven Agent') {
   ci.checkout();
}
```

Shared library function:

```
def checkout(Map config=[:], Closure body={}) {
    stage('Check Out') 
    {         
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'Github-ims-devops-practice', url: 'https://github.com/ims-devops-practice/spec-files.git']]]);
    }
}
```

The console log is as follows:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Maven Agent in /home/ec2-user/workspace/springboot-pipeline@5
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Check Out)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Check Out)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Check Out)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Check Out)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Check Out)
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:131)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
Finished: FAILURE
```

P.S.- Shortened the console log for ease.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your shared library `checkout` function is calling itself endlessly.

Comment: Solution would be to rename `def checkout(Map config=[:], Closure body={}) {` to anything other than `checkout`

Comment: oh, it's a keyword issue?